# Java: How to open url's of different types like mailto and http?

Tags: java, url

I know there are `Desktop.browse()` and `Desktop.mail()`.

However I would like to open all of the different links wirh the same function. E.g. if the url is `mailto:...`, open it with the default email application, if the url is `http://...`, open it by using default browser.

Is it really necessary to specify all the different cases for all the different link types/applications, or is there a generic way to open any link, similar to how a browser opens links from "a href" html tags?

Comment: Maybe `browse` can do that? What happens if you give it a `mailto:` URL ?

Comment: @Thilo Nope, doesn't work. Nothing happens... Also in the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) it says that "browse()" opens a browser.